# Tracking who Exports Reports

Tags: data-export, workbench, tracking-extract, eventlogfile

Yesterday I exported a couple of reports and wanted to track these which has hit the 24hr mark.  The following day I went to workbench and through Querying the EventLogFile Object and looking at the EventType, the only EventTypes that were present were, Login and Logout.  I also tried using the REST Exploring and providing this request in:

`/services/data/v44.0/query?q=SELECT+Id+,+EventType+,+LogDate+,+LogFileLength+,+LogFile+FROM+EventLogFile++WHERE+EventType+=+'ReportExport' and still nothing is populated.`

Any reason why the Exported Reports are not showing up?

Comment: Did you license the SFDC feature that permits Event Monitoring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't licensed the Event Monitoring feature, per [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/event_monitoring/event_monitoring_intro):

> Enterprise, Unlimited, and Performance Edition organizations have free
>   access to the insecure external assets, login, and logout event log
>   files with one-day data retention. For an extra cost, you can access
>   all log file types with 30-day data retention.

So, you might not be able to see the Exported Reports